# Iron router: call to Meteor.user() from router controller returns error

Tags: meteor, iron-router

In Iron router path controller I'm trying to load different templates depending on user login status like this:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('start', {
    path: '/',
    controller: StartController
    });
})

StartController = RouteController.extend({
    template: Meteor.user() ? 'home' : 'landing',
    waitOn: function() {
        return [Meteor.subscribe('something')]
    }
});
```

However I get exception in console:
"...Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions..."

I don't really understand what that error means, and what Am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've posted is executed on the server. On the server, `Meteor.user()` can only be executed in methods.

However, even if this error wouldn't exist, your code wouldn't function as you wish anyway. `Meteor.user() ? 'home' : 'landing'` will be executed once in the beginning (when the user probably isn't logged in), and won't be re-executed when the user signs in/out.

Read [this](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/dev/DOCS.md#before-and-after-hooks) in the docs, which is kind of doing what you want.